# custom rake task error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to run a custom rake test.  Here's the code:

```
task :test => :environment do
  user = User.first
  puts "Winner: #{user.email}"
  puts "test"
end
```

But when I run it, I get this error.

```
$ rake test

rake aborted!
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any insight on why I don't have access to the class User?  Even though I have :environment in there?

Comment: nevermind.  Don't name custom rake tasks "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to something similar recently. I tried to get the `id` and I was not able to get this to work until I used a mapping. Try this:

```
task :test => :environment do 
  email = User.first.map(&:email)
  puts "Winner: #{email}"
  puts "test" 
end
```

I am not saying this is the proper way to do it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is for some reason you don't get any users for

```
User.first
```

You could check this by using debugger or simply try

```
User.first.nil?
```